# Google Chrome issue - Unable to retrive button(HTML tag) value while submitting form

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, google-chrome, button

I have a scenario in which a button value is not being posted while submitting form in ASP.NET MVC controller.

This is happening only for **Google Chrome** browser. For all other browsers Firefox, IE, I am getting **Submit_0** value in Controller.

//Server side

```
public ActionResult Answers(string id, SurveyViewModel model, string Submit, string button)
{


 string[] buttonParts = button.Split(new char[]{'_'});
..

...

}
```

//Client Side

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Answers", "Survey"))
{

<button value="Submit_0" name="button" onclick="document.forms[0].submit();"><span><span>Submit</span></span></button>
}
```

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if it is because the way you wired the button. Why don't you use something like this instead?

```
<button type="submit" name="button" value="submit_0">Submit</button>
```

Notice that the button has a type of submit (which eliminate the need to call document.forms[0].submit() manually)

Comment: Hi,The reason I am using above code is that there are multiple buttons in the form which need to submit the form. I am not sure but as per my knowledge there should ideally be one submit button. That is the reason I am using above code. Also, this code runs in all other browsers. Only Google Chrome is causing this issue.